# Is there a panning option in Google timeline chart?

Tags: angular, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

Is panning possible in timeline charts of google charts?

When I started using i find there is no option for that. Is there any option in new release or currently does it has that option?

Comment: no panning on timeline chart, closest would be using a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) instead...

Comment: TY @WhiteHat . Is  panning available for Gantt charts of google?

Comment: no panning on Gantt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Panning or Zooming options available in Google Timeline/Gantt Charts.